# My appengine app can´t share to Twitter now. New Twitter API restriction?

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter

I have a mobile app which uses AppEngine/python as backend. Users have a way to login and share their content in Twitter and Facebook.

The problem since yesterday is that users can't login or share o twitter. (facebook is ok) I'm suspecting it might have something to do with hte new Twitter API restrictions, I've   searched for answers all last night but can't find it, trying to see if anyone else is having this issue.

The error info in the log is:
...

> ApplicationError: 2 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 712, in **call**
>       handler.post(*groups)
>   File "/base/data/home/apps/weddarapp/4.361251603797223739/push.py", line 83, in post
>       self.get()
>
> File "/base/data/home/apps/weddarapp/4.361251603797223739/push.py", line 78, in get
>       method = urlfetch.POST)
>
> File "/base/data/home/apps/weddarapp/4.361251603797223739/oauth.py", line 204, in make_request
>       protected, method, headers).get_result()
>
> File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
>       return self.__get_result_hook(self)
>
> File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 369, in _get_fetch_result
>       raise DownloadError(str(err))
>
> DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2

...

I understand it's oAuth, but nothing changed on our side, so it must be from twitter. I don't think it's a coincidence. couldn't find an updated version of our oAuth.py file.

thanks

Comment: About this, I found that it's indeed a Twitter/AppEngine issue and they (Twitter) are aware of it and trying to fix it, for all I understand at the moment.

Check: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3218

Comment: Also, there is an ongoing discussion on the App Engine group about what appears to be the same issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/29jA7WO3NlM

Comment: Hi Bryce, thanx. Yep, it was a twitter issue, they solved it, check here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3218